# perl parse command line arguments using shift command

Tags: perl

I have a question regarding parsing command line arguments and the use of the shift command in Perl.

I wanted to use this line to launch my Perl script

```
/home/scripts/test.pl -a --test1 -b /path/to/file/file.txt
```

So I want to parse the command line arguments. This is part of my script where I do that

```
if ($arg eq "-a") {
    $main::john = shift(@arguments);
} elsif ($arg eq "-b") {
    $main::doe = shift(@arguments);
}
```

I want to use then these arguments in a `$command` variable that will be executed afterwards

```
my $var1=$john;
my $var2=$doe;
my $command = "/path/to/tool/tool --in $line --out $outputdir $var1 $var2";
&execute($command);
```

Now here are two problems that I encounter:

It should not be obligatory to specify `-a` & `-b` at the command line. But what happens now is that when I don't specify `-a`, I get the message that I'm using an uninitialized value at the line where the variable is defined

Second problem: `$var2` will now equal `$doe` so it will be in this case `/path/to/file/file.txt`. However I want `$var2` to be equal to `--text /path/to/file/file.txt`. Where should I specify this `--text`. It cannot be standardly in the `$command`, because then it will give a problem when I don't specify `-b`. Should I do it when I define `$doe`, but how then?

Comment: `perldoc GetOpt::Long`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should build your command string according to the contents of the variables

Like this

```
my $var1 = $john;
my $var2 = $doe;
my $command = "/path/to/tool/tool --in $line --out $outputdir";

$command .= " $var1"        if defined $var1;
$command .= " --text $var2" if defined $var2;

execute($command);
```

Also

- Don't use ampersands `&` when you are calling Perl subroutine. That hasn't been good practice for eighteen years now
- Don't use package variables like `$main:xxx`. Lexical variables (declared with `my`) are almost all that is necessary
- As [Alnitak *says in the comment*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36980987/perl-parse-command-line-arguments-using-shift-command#comment61517034_36980987) you should really be using the [`Getopt::Long`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Getopt::Long) module to avoid introducing errors into your command-line parsing

Answer (score 0):

GetOpt::Long might be an option: http://search.cpan.org/~jv/Getopt-Long-2.48/lib/Getopt/Long.pm

Regarding your sample:

You didn't say what should happen if `-a` or `-b` are missing, but defaults may solve your problem:

```
# Use 'join' as default if $var1 is not set
my $var1 = $john // 'john';
# Use an empty value as default if $var2 is not set
my $var2 = $doe // '';
```

Regarding the `--text` prefix:

Do you want to set it always?

```
my $command = "/path/to/tool/tool --in $line --out $outputdir $var1 --text $var2";
```

Or do you want to set it if `-b` = `$var2` has been set?

```
# Prefix
my $var2 = "--text $john";

# Prefix with default
my $var2 = defined $john ? "--text $john" : '';
# Same, but long format
my $var2 = ''; # Set default
if ($john) {
    $var2 = "--text $john";
}
```